# How to generate an Instagram Access Token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-manager

How can I generate an Instagram access token?

In short, I need to automate uploading an image to Instagram. Thus, I believe that a prerequisite for this is to register a Facebook app and then register a test user.

I am able to register a Facebook app. However, I am unable to register a test user:

[image]

This error appears to be an ongoing issue with developers and is not going away.

What other options are available for generating an access token, so that I can use the Graph API?

Comment: Use a real account, that has a role in the app.

Comment: In Meta Business Suite, I only see an option for adding email addresses for contributors and not Instagram accounts. Is there any documentation on how I can use a real account that has a role in the app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles